# Issues when adding 2 Jssor sliders

Tags: javascript, jquery, jssor

I tried to add 2 JSSOR sliders ("carousel-slider.source & thumbnail-07.source") to my html site. But it didn't work. It works fine only with one slider.
What is the issue behind this?

Comment: How should we know that without seeing the code?

Comment: Thnaks for pointing out, michael . It's my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To combine multi sliders in one page, please use different name.

For example, the name of the first slider is 'slider1', please make the second named 'slider2'.

So, please open thumbnail-07.source.html, replace all 'slider1' with 'slider2'.